# Pose drifting in featureless environment

Tags: google-project-tango

The Tango pose is drifting around while holding the device still when the camera is facing a region without too many distinct features, i.e. facing a white wall. Typically the drift direction is away from the target it is facing. I understand it is hard for the device to localize itself under such a condition due to lack of landmarks. However, is there a mechanism to let the device know that it has difficulties in getting reliable pose, then I am able to tell the device stop doing something until the device is relocalized by going back to the area with rich landmarks or features.

Note: the pose status is still showing valid in this case.

Comment: any attempt to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please check tango_client_api_header
you are looking for TANGO_POSE_INVALID

another way you want is integrating UX library.
check this below:
https://developers.google.com/project-tango/ux/ux-framework#exception_handling

or you can write up your own handle for different module.

Comment: The first way might not work because the pose status is still valid in this case. I will try the other two ways. Thank you for your help, sandy!